# Audit table only in specific cases

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have a table that have a lot of updates and inserts. My idea is to run a job once a day that calls a procedure to make some corrections on this table that may occur in the data, like `rtrim`, `ltrim`, remove tabs, line breaks, etc.

What I want is to log on a table the `ID`, `Original Value` and `Modified Value` only of these jobs, to keep track of these changes.

Is there a way to do that?

I don't mind the changes made on the other ways and anyway, I don't want to waste resources on it.

Thank you

Comment: In your procedure itself write the code to capture the before value & after value. And do insert in the Audit table. So that, in this special case only you will do audit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could approach this.  This method uses the [output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) clause of an [update query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) to audit changes.  We are going to use the special tables [inserted and deleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) to capture the old and new values.

If you are planning to run your updates daily you could embed this technique within an [SSIS job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  The [SQL Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189237.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can run the job on a fixed schedule, for you.

## Sample Data

```
-- Sample data table.
DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
        ID      INT,
        Value   VARCHAR(255)
    )
;

-- Sample audit table.
DECLARE @T_AUDIT TABLE
    (
        ID          INT,
        OldValue    VARCHAR(255),
        NewValue    VARCHAR(255)
    )
;

-- Let's add some records to experiment with...
INSERT INTO @T
    (
        ID,
        Value
    )
VALUES
    (1, ' abc'),
    (2, 'def '),
    (3, '***    ****')  -- Using 4 spaces to represent a tab.
;
```

## Update Query

```
-- Update data table, and write changes to audit table.
UPDATE
    @T
SET
    Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(Value, '    ', '')))
OUTPUT
    inserted.ID,
    deleted.Value AS OldValue,
    inserted.Value AS NewValue
INTO
    @T_AUDIT
;

-- Verify result.
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @T_AUDIT
;
```

This returns the below.  I've replaced spaces with underscores, to make it easier to read.

```
ID  OldValue        NewValue
1   _abc            abc
2   def_            def
3   ****____****    x
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!